# Comparing two columns, same row, for first value that doesn't match

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets, one is a mirror sheet, "Sheet2," that I use to store the values of the other sheet, "Sheet1."  My goal is to have a function compare the two sheets for differences.  The best way i could think of was by comparing column A from Sheet1 to column A from Sheet2.  I found a few functions that compared 2 columns but it did it looking for values from one column and finding it in the other column.  Or by returning all the values in those cells that had a matching value, regardless of what row it was in. But I don't want the values in the cells, necessarily.  I want to find the first row where the two columns stop matching. I'm fairly new to Javascript so I still can't comprehend the whole `for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++)` stuff.

But I'm sure I will need to know how to use it for this function I need.  Here's what I tried using but instead of giving me row ranges, it gave me an array of values that were the same, if I changed it to `if(lookup[i][0]!==range[j][0]){`  it gave me all the possible combinations that weren't matching. This is from [stackoverflow.com/questions/42044903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044903/google-script-compare-two-columns-and-if-match-paste-matching-value)

```
function findDifference() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var lr=s.getLastRow()
  var lookup = s.getRange(2,1,lr-1,2).getValues();
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2") 
  var lr1=s1.getLastRow()
  var range = s1.getRange(2,1,lr1-1,2).getValues();
  var lookupRange = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++) {
     var  test=lookup[i][0]
         if(lookup[i][0]!==range[j][0]){
           lookupRange.push([range[j][0],range[j][1],lookup[i][0],lookup[i][1],]);
     }}}
   s1.getRange(10,1,lookupRange.length,4).setValues(lookupRange); 
}
```

I feel like there's a very similar function for what I'm trying to do that already exists, but I can't seem to find it or come up with how it would work because I'm new and don't know all the tricks.
Something like:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var s2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
var ColumnA1 = s1.getRange('A:A').getValues()
var ColumnA2 = s2.getRange('A:A').getValues()
var Row = Function()
///Some function I can't think of using where
if(ColumnA1 + Row !== ColumnA2 + Row){
???.getRow()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you had was "kinda' helpful but it did not solve your particular question. On the other hand, your `if(ColumnA1 + Row !== ColumnA2 + Row){` wasn't really helpful either.

Regrettably you DO need to "comprehend the whole for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++) stuff", though it isn't actually that complicated.

In the following answer, there are basically three elements.

- setup sheet1, and get the data
- setup sheet2, and get the data
- loop through the rows and compare the value on a given line from one sheet to the other.
- the `for` statement signifies the loop
- `i` is simply a counter variable
- `i=0` means that the starting value is zero. In javascript arrays, zero always the first value set.
- `i < Sheet1Data.length` signifies how many time the loop will run. In this case, it will run while i is less then the number of lines in the array. Remember, i starts with zero, so "less than" the totoal number of lines will be fine.
- `i++` means that each time the code loops, it increments i by one.. So, i starts with 0, then 1, 2, 3 and so on.

**How to find the first row where the two columns stop matching**

- View the Logs (View > Logs).

You can see on line 32 and 38 of the code `Logger.log` statements. These record the line number and whether the line values in each sheet match.

---

```
function so56195933() {
  // setup Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // setup Sheet1
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var s1LastRow = s1.getLastRow();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet 1 Last row = "+s1LastRow);
  var Sheet1DataRange = s1.getRange(1,1,s1LastRow);
  var Sheet1Data = Sheet1DataRange.getValues();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet 1 data range = "+Sheet1DataRange.getA1Notation());
  var Sheet1length = Sheet1Data.length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet1 length = "+Sheet1length);

  // setup Sheet2
  var s2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2") 
  var s2LastRow=s2.getLastRow();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet 2 Last row = "+s2LastRow);
  var Sheet2DataRange = s2.getRange(1,1,s2LastRow);
  var Sheet2Data = Sheet2DataRange.getValues();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet 2 data range = "+Sheet2DataRange.getA1Notation());
  var Sheet2length = Sheet2Data.length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet2 length = "+Sheet2length);

  // Loop through rows compare value per each sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < Sheet1Data.length; i++) {
    var s1data = Sheet1Data[i][0];
    var s2data = Sheet2Data[i][0];
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: Line: "+i+", s1data: "+s1data+" Vs s2data: "+s2data);
    if (s1data !=s2data){
      // sheets values don't balance
      Logger.log("Line: "+i+". Sheets are NOT equal. Sheet1 = "+s1data+", Sheet2 = "+s2data);
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      // sheets values balance
      Logger.log("Line: "+i+". Sheets are equal, value: "+s1data);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**This is my test data**

[image: My Test Data]

Comment: This was really helpful and insightful!  Thank you.  I was just wondering what does the return false do in this case?  And how would I get it to return a cell, row, or column from values?

Comment: Is it  "+i+" in the first if condition?  I put 
``var falseRow = +i+ 
Logger.log(falseRow)``
and got back "3Logger"  So I guess I'm close?

Comment: oh just make it ``= i``

Comment: `return false;` doesn't actually add any extra value, my bad. It works just as effectively with `return;`

Comment: `And how would I get it to return a cell, row, or column from values?` The key is the value of "i". Row: `+i+1` (because it's zero-based); Column: in this case we're only looking at a single column (Column A), in the array value "Sheet1Data[i][0]", the righthand value - `0`; again, add one to get the actual spreadsheet column number. Cell: the row and column give you the cell - if you want A1 notation, then have a look at [Convert column index into corresponding column letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229180/).

Comment: New question, is there a way to do this for both column 1 and 2?  for example if col 1 says Sun in both sheets, but col 2 says Sun in the first sheet buy Moon in the second.  Is there a way to where it checks that and returns it as the first row??

Comment: Nevermind I just added 2 more lines and then said ``if(s1data + s1Bdata != s2data + s2Bdata){``